# Contents of an inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

Is there a command that lists all the information contained in an Inode of a file/directory?
Such as User ID of file, Group ID of file, Device ID, File size, Date of creation, Permission, Owner of the file, File protection flag, Link counter to determine number of hard links, and so on...

Thank you!

Comment: Note that depending on the filesystem used, "date of creation" (more commonly know as "birth time") may not be available.

Answer (score 2):

The `stat` command is what you are looking for.

Example use:

```
$ stat .tmux.conf
  File: '.tmux.conf'
  Size: 166             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc03h/64515d    Inode: 524688      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1002/ myself)   Gid: ( 1002/ myself)
Access: 2020-03-24 10:41:02.240195399 +0100
Modify: 2018-07-18 16:19:45.228487544 +0200
Change: 2018-07-18 16:19:45.228487544 +0200
 Birth: -
```

See also `man stat` on your system.

Note that the default output format will vary greatly between different Unixes.